# Проблема с путями запуска внешнего приложения

Tags: python, 1с, резервное-копирование

Ниже приведен скрипт на питоне для создания резервной копии базы данных 1с на сервере Win.

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime

print("Запуск скрипта резервного копирования 1С")

# путь к 1С
# set EXEC_PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\1cv8\common\1cestart.exe"
EXEC_PATH = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\1cv8\common\1cestart.exe"'
# Путь до папки с резервными копиями
BACKUP_PATH = r'D:\backup'
# Префикс названия файла резервной копии
BACKUP_PREFIX = 'monolit'
# логин пользователя 1С
LOGIN = 'Администратор'
# пароль пользователя 1С
PASSWORD = ''
# ИБ:
# /F - файловый вариант, /S - клиент-серверный вариант
# для файлового варианта - указывается только путь, например /F"C:\1c_base\"
# для клиент-серверного - указывается Кластер\Имя_ИБ, например /S"1c\1c_base"
# BASE=r'/S"1c\new_tc"'
BASE = r'/F"C:\base\Монолит бух\"'

# Отключаем пользователей
os.system(
    f'{EXEC_PATH} ENTERPRISE {BASE} /N{LOGIN} /P{PASSWORD}'
    '/WA- /AU- /DisableStartupMessages /CЗавершитьРаботуПользователей')

# Разрешаем доступ к базе
os.system(
    f'{EXEC_PATH} ENTERPRISE {BASE} /N{LOGIN} /P{PASSWORD}'
    '/WA- /AU- /DisableStartupMessages /CРазрешитьРаботуПользователей /UCКодРазрешения')

# Делаем резервную копию
os.system(
    f'{EXEC_PATH} CONFIG {BASE} /N{LOGIN} /P{PASSWORD} /Out"%LOG_FILE%"'
    f'/DumpIB"{BACKUP_PATH}"\\{BACKUP_PREFIX}_{datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")}.dt')
```

При попытке запуска выдает:

```
Запуск скрипта резервного копирования 1С
"C:\Program" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
"C:\Program" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
"C:\Program" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Методом научного тыка нашел что проблема возникает когда в команду запуска добавляется содержимое переменной BASE. Хотя думаю проблему вызывает всю содержимое команды запуска находящееся правее слова ENTERPRISE.
То есть такая конструкция работает:

```py
os.system(f'{EXEC_PATH'} ENTERPRISE')
```

А вот такая уже нет:

```py
os.system(f'{EXEC_PATH'} ENTERPRISE {BASE}')
```

Пожалуйста помогите разобраться

Comment: попробуй получать значения переменных* внутри скрипта и далее формируй текстовую_строку для запуска;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал код вот на такой и у меня все отлично заработало.

```py
temp_file = Path(tempfile.gettempdir()).joinpath(config['backup_prefix'] + dt.now().strftime('%Y%m%d') + '.dt')
cmd = [config['exec_path'], 'DESIGNER', '/F', config['base'], '/N', config['login'], '/P', config['password'], '/WA-', '/DumpIB', temp_file]
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Сначала надо убрать проблемы кодировки, чтобы видеть что отвечает консоль.

Программа передает значения переменных в UTF-8 (она же 65001), а консоль работает по-умолчанию в 866, ответы приходят в 866. Например PyCharm выдаст такой ответ как в примере ("иероглифами").

Например, это можно убрать с помощью:

```
chcp 65001>nul&&
```

Потом надо убрать двойные кавычки в пути до exe-шника:

```
EXEC_PATH = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\1cv8\common\1cestart.exe'
```

Возможно для нормализации пути будет полезным использовать os.path.abspath (но полезность это функции в данном примере сомнительна):

```
EXEC_PATH = os.path.abspath(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\1cv8\common\1cestart.exe')
```

Так или иначе, кавычки в примере надо ставить не в переменную, а уже в консольную команду - так консоль не будет "спотыкаться" на пробеле.

Конечная строка будет выглядеть так:

```
os.system(
    f'chcp 65001>nul&&"{EXEC_PATH}" ENTERPRISE {BASE} /N{LOGIN} /P{PASSWORD}'
    '/WA- /AU- /DisableStartupMessages /CЗавершитьРаботуПользователей')
```

Протестировал на своей базе запуск уже отредактированного скрипта прямо из PyCharm, нашел пару ошибок в моем исходном комментарии, из-за которых скрипт ошибок не выдавал, но и с 1С ничего не делал. После замены "||" на "&&" все отрабатывает как надо.

Comment: При проверке на моей базе, успешно отработали 1ая и 2ая команды (комментировал все кроме нужно).. Третий скрипт для копирования по какой-то причине не стал выгружать dt, а удалил папку куда должны были сохраняться копии, причем бесследно